# Is there any function to map vector subtraction to its coordinates?

Tags: vector, geometry, linear-algebra

[image]

When i subtract vector the resultant vector is starting from origin, how can i map this result to the A to B vector coordinates?

Comment: i want OC to be placed in dotted line AB

Comment: You can't recover either A or B from the coordinates of B-A.  For instance, note you would have got the same vector if A had been (2,4) and B had been (4,3).  Just knowing that B-A=(2,-1) can't distinguish between those cases.

Comment: so there is no any way to get AB?

Comment: Perhaps it would be wise to describe what are you going to do with result.

Comment: i need to drop a projection to this vector from (gesture vector)